# PHP random generated id does not match database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a login system integrated into my website, but I am a video game programmer and want to integrate my website into my games. I am using PHP to check the password of a user and its suppose to return a random userid that I can use later on to validate the user. I am doing a POST request from the game to the webserver to validate the user info, I am not able to host a dedicated server for the user auth and my current webhost does not allow remote access to the MYSQL database, so this is my only option. Here is the last bit of code that is giving me fits.

```
$userid = $this->generateRandID();
$time = time();

$database->updateUserField($_POST["username"], "userid", $userid);
$database->addActiveUser($_POST["username"], $time);
$database->removeActiveGuest($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
echo($userid);
```

It is suppose to add the user as an active user and update the userid field in the mysql database, then echo the userid for me to then save in the game. The problem is the userid echoed doesn't seem to be the same as the one in the database.
Here is updateUserField, its just a shortcut for me so I don't have to change lots of lines of code if I need to change it for whatever reason.

```
function updateUserField($username, $field, $value){
    return mysqli_query( $this->connection, "UPDATE ".TBL_USERS." SET ".$field." = '$value' WHERE username = '$username'");
}
```

Comment: for the sanity of people having to read your code, please use sprintf

Comment: @Galen Why does that matter? I don't see how that will do any good at all.

Comment: It will make your code much more readable

Comment: I am not sure how the sprintf function applies to my code seeing as it returns just a value, or am I not getting what the functions purpose is?

Comment: `sprintf( "UPDATE %s SET %s = %s WHERE username = %s", TBL_USERS, $field, $value, $username)` is how it could look with sprintf

Comment: It's not an answer to your question, its just a suggestion for the future.

Comment: You're not checking if the queries succeeded at all. **NEVER** assume a query succeeded. Even if the sql statement itself is perfectly valid, there's far too many other reasons for things to blow up to NOT check

Comment: @legobear154 Could you please state what you are trying to achieve exactly? Do you need to have one record per user? Are user records persistent or are they only kept while the user is online?

Comment: @MarcB I am sorry I forgot to check if it succeeded, I usually do that and I was a bit more careless with this because I was getting frustrated with the fact the echoed value was not equal to the one in the database.

Comment: @freeatnet Users sign up on my website and have a unique username, pass, etc. Then users can log into the website from within one of my games and the games can store different things on the database that is linked to each user. Some examples are like achievements, different kinds of stats like the level of their character and things like that, as well as leaderboards. The user records are persistent, but the userid is different after each login to help stop session jacking and other things that can compromise a user account. I hope that clears up what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

From your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180239/php-random-generated-id-does-not-match-database#comment14671012_11180239) it sounds like the reason you are trying to replace user IDs with random numbers is to add a certain security level to your application. I believe a better approach would be to handle sessions separately from your user data persistance.
At the moment, the industry standard in managing third-party applications' programmatic access to your system is oAuth. You can check out the [official oAuth docs](http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/) or a [beginner's guide to oAuth](http://hueniverse.com/oauth/). While the standard oAuth workflow assumes that the user will authenticate directly on a webpage on your site, there's also ["two-legged oAuth"](http://blog.nerdbank.net/2011/06/what-is-2-legged-oauth.html) that allows the user to provide their credentials in the third-party application itself (in your case, your game).
Some of the reasons to implement oAuth is security, separation of authorization from data or purpose of your site, client and provider [library support](http://oauth.net/code/).

Comment: The problem, or so it seems to me, is that for me to use oAuth with php I need to install an extension onto the server. I am not able to do that because I don't have access to the server and I am not able to do any socket connections either. I am in quite a predicament with this. By all means of course, tell me I am wrong if I am, but from what I have seen on their site, I am not currently able to implement oAuth into my website. I am actually starting to rewrite the account system completely because of this problem I am having.